# Argument #1 ($mailable) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable, string given

Tags: email, events, laravel-8, listener, send

I try to send an email with a new created post. But I get this error, but I don't understand what is wrong?

Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail::send(): Argument #1 ($mailable) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable, string given, called in /Users/mattiasandersson/Documents/Utveckling/TESTER/Event_Listener/app/Listeners/NotifyPostCreated.php on line 37

```
public function handle(PostCreated $event)

{

    $users = User::all();

    foreach($users as $user) {

        Mail::to($user->email)->send('emails.post_created', $event->post);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The value in send() should extend mailable
Assuming you have a PostMail class  as shown below
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class PostMail extends Mailable 
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $post;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($post)
    {
        //
        $this->post=$post;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this`enter code here`
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("Mail from posts")->view('mail.Test_mail');
    }
}
```

Then on your handle method you can

```
public function handle()
    {
        $data = User::all();
        $post=$this->post;
       
        
        
        $postdata = new PostMail($post);
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $input['email'] = $value->email;
            $input['name'] = $value->name;
           
            Mail::to($input['email'])->send($postdata);
        }
    }
```

Note:Mail::to($input['email'])->send($postdata); $postdata is of type PostMail which extends Mailable.
Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).